# Difference Between SciPy.Stats.powerlaw and powerlaw package

Tags: python, scipy, power-law

I am trying to simulate random variables that are power law distributed based on my understanding of the definition in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law) and several other resources where the consensus is that a "power law distributed random variable" has the probability density function (PDF) of the form [formula1](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=p(x)%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Calpha-1%7D%7Bx_%7Bmin%7D%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7Bx_%7Bmin%7D%7D%5Cright)%5E%7B-%5Calpha%7D) and in particular, I'm interested in the case where `x_min=1`, which reduces to
[formula2](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=p(x)%20%3D%20(%5Calpha-1)(x)%5E%7B-%5Calpha%7D).

However, I've noticed that while the `powerlaw` python package seems to use this definition, `scipy.stats.powerlaw` uses a slightly different definition for powerlaw distributions and that is [formula3](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=p(x)%20%3D%20ax%5E%7Ba-1%7D) where alpha is positive and x is between 0 and 1 (inclusive), which we can rearrange if we let [formula4](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=a%3D1-%5Calpha) to the form [formula5](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=p(x)%20%3D%20-(%5Calpha-1)(x)%5E%7B-%5Calpha%7D), which would match the form of formula2 (above) but with a negative sign in front of it, with the caveat that alpha would then be negative in the `powerlaw` version.

The reason I was interested in using the SciPy version is that the Scipy package defines a "percent point function" (ppf) which can be used to generate a set of random values from uniformly distributed probabilities (i.e. the PPF is the inverse of the CDF).

So I'm trying to understand the difference between how the two packages define powerlaw distributions (are they even talking about the same thing?) so that I can translate from my distribution parameters (x_min and alpha) which seem to work under the Powerlaw model to the SciPy.Stats.powerlaw model in order to be able to use the PPF function.

Alternatively, if there is a way to use the Powerlaw package to generate random values from a set of uniformly distributed probabilities, I would greatly appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right.

`scipy.stats.powerlaw` defines

$$
p(x, \alpha) = \alpha x^{\alpha - 1}
$$

`powerlaw` is much more complex and I don't know it very well but (as I can understand) when you generate random variates from a continuous distribution with $x_{min}=1$, it defines a PDF

$$
p(x, \beta) = -(\beta - 1) x^{-\beta}
$$

so that $\beta = 1 - \alpha$.

You can verify this.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sps
import powerlaw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# scipy.stats.powerlaw
alpha = 5
# powerlaw
beta = 1 - alpha
```

Let's define `scipy.stats.powerlaw` distribution with $\alpha$

```
# define scipy distribution
dist = sps.powerlaw(a=alpha)
x = np.linspace(dist.ppf(.0001), dist.ppf(.9999), 1000)
pdf = dist.pdf(x)
plt.plot(x, pdf)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('PDF');
```

[image]

and take 1000 random variates

```
# take 1000 random variates
np.random.seed(0)
rvs = dist.rvs(1000)
```

then, let's define `powerlaw` distribution with $\beta$ and take 1000 random variates

```
# define powerlaw distribution
theoretical_distribution = powerlaw.Power_Law(
    xmin=1., parameters=[beta], discrete=False
)
# take 1000 random variates
np.random.seed(0)
simulated_data = theoretical_distribution.generate_random(1000)
```

and plot both

```
plt.hist(simulated_data, histtype='step', label='powerlaw')
plt.hist(rvs, histtype='step', label='scipy.stats')
plt.title('Random variates')
plt.legend(loc='upper left');
```

[image]

As you can see, they come from the same distribution, and we can check fitting the random variates obtained with `powerlaw` to `scipy.stats.powerlaw`

```
# fit powerlaw random variates with scipy.stats
fit_simulated_data = sps.powerlaw.fit(simulated_data, loc=0, scale=1)
print('alpha:', fit_simulated_data[0])
```

that gives

```
alpha: 4.948952195656542
```

which is the $\alpha$ we defined for `scipy.stats.powerlaw`.

Comment: Did I get the PDF for `powerlaw` wrong then? Because in your answer the two PDFs are the same, but for me the `powerlaw` PDF has an opposite sign. Also, in your example, `beta = -4`, and I was given the impression in the papers `powerlaw` refers to that it is greater than 1. Conversely, if I'm working with a distribution with `beta > 1`, then alpha under `scipy.stats.powerlaw` would be negative, and they explicitly say it must be positive. The one last part I forgot to mention is that in `scipy.stats.powerlaw` `0 <= x <= 1`, whereas in `powerlaw` (and what I'm trying to simulate) `x >= x_min`.

Comment: I'm not confident enough with `powerlaw` package to be able to help you in your specific case. I can only suggest you to take a look at the code implementation https://github.com/jeffalstott/powerlaw/blob/06e3f0315f26819f26b847d9bbe7e0885c2b4ca1/powerlaw.py and find directly there the PDF that better suits your needs.